# Installing Wildfly on Windows 10 is complaining about dependancies

Tags: java, windows, wildfly-10

I'm trying to install Wildfly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HUFaL--SwI) and [this other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljeDnSV1bb0) too on youtube.

- Windows 10
- I've installed JDK9
- WildFly10

When I type **standalone**, I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jboss.modules.ClassLoaderLocalLoader$1
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jboss.mod
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Then I get also a series of error, which basically says that: `one or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available.`

I'm completely new to Java world. I don't know why I'm getting those errors, yet in both tutorials there are just few simple steps to follow.

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

```
Calling "C:\dev\tools\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9" path doesn't exist
```

Comment: First of all try jdk8

Comment: Now `wildfly` is complaining that it can't find `jdk9` (see update). Seems like I need to downgrade wildfly as well.

Comment: Unless you installed Java 8 into the `jdk-9` directory it is obvious why Wildfly complains about a missing Java. But you solved the problem by updating Wildfly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Wildfly 10.0.0.Final. I've replaced it with 10.1.0.Final, now it's working.

Interesting!!!